# How to access a JLabel from another method?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm working on a GUI application and what i want my code to do is that after clicking the sole button that you can perceive in my swing-based GUI, the 2 jLabels present within it make the String "Working" perceivable to the user. Here's my code:

```
public class DiligentGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public DiligentGUI() {
    initComponents();
}
void a()
{
  fahrenheitLabel.setText("Working");  
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    tempTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    celsiusLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    convertButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    fahrenheitLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Celsius Converter");

    tempTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            tempTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    celsiusLabel.setText("Celsius");

    convertButton.setText("Convert");
    convertButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            convertButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    fahrenheitLabel.setText("Fahrenheit");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()

.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(tempTextField,  
javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,  
javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                    .addComponent(celsiusLabel))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(convertButton)


.addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(fahrenheitLabel)))
            .addContainerGap(59, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {convertButton, tempTextField});

    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(tempTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(celsiusLabel))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(convertButton)
                .addComponent(fahrenheitLabel))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void tempTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                             

private void convertButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

DiligentGUI b = new DiligentGUI();
b.a();
celsiusLabel.setText("Working");
}                                             

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DiligentGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DiligentGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DiligentGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DiligentGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new DiligentGUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel celsiusLabel;
private javax.swing.JButton convertButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel fahrenheitLabel;
private javax.swing.JTextField tempTextField;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

As you can see, there are 2 jLabels inside this: fahrenheitLabel and celsiusLabel. I've created an auxiliary method dubbed as 'a' that should change the status of fahrenheitLabel to "Working". I'm unable to realize the desired output. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not happening because you are creating another object of class `DiligentGUI` in your `convertButtonActionPerformed` method. This is creating another `JFrame`. You cannot see it coz you did not set it visible by `d.setVisible(true)`.

Make this change in your

```
private void convertButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    a();  // This will call the a() method in the current running instance. 
    celsiusLabel.setText("Working");
}
```

Comment: Gee, your method does work, but as you pointed out a new JFrame is being created. In fact every time i hit the sole button available, a new JFrame is created. I don't want this to happen. I want all the manipulations and alterations to be visible in just the one JFrame that i begin with

Comment: it wont create a new frame after you change the method as i said. if my answer works for you, please accept it.